# What's the difference between "appear like" and "look like"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What's the difference between "appear like" and "look like"?

> 1. *Known officially as the National Aquatics Center, the building's design and its translucent, blue-toned outside skin make it **appear like** a cube of bubbles* ([Haici Cidian](http://dict.cn/Known%20officially%20as%20the%20National%20Aquatics%20Center,%20the%20building%27s%20design%20and%20its%20translucent,%20blue-toned%20outside%20skin%20make%20it%20appear%20like%20a%20cube%20of%20bubbles_2E))
> 2. *It **looks like** a saddle*

Answer (score 4):

Appear is another word for seem - something which shows itself gradually/slowly can appear. `The sun appears over the horizon.`

Look is more direct and explains something which you can see immediately.Look like means something bear a physical resemblance to; `She looks like her mother.`

Comment: Good answer. +1. Also to note that appear/seem/look may be used to mean the same thing. *This appears to be a big problem; This seems to be a big problem; This looks like a big problem.*